# Is it a good practice to access session data in view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Which is better from design and coding point of view: accessing session data in the view directly or loading them in the controller and passing them to the view using a viewbag?

Answer (score 1):

MVC wont really care if you do something in your controller or your views but i agree with shaftpolls for not hurting the mvc pattern. Since Session is already inside the ViewData wrapper, you can access it directly in the View.
Be aware, that the Session object should only contain simple, non-sensitive data like user picked language, or custom ui-colorsheme.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use Session, you should get that data on the server side and then pass it to the View using Strongly Typed properties in a View Model rather than using the ViewBag.

So let's say you have a property on your view model which is of type `IENumerable<SelectListItem>` and inside your view you will use the strongly typed version of the Html.DropDownListFor helper to bind to the model this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProductId, Model.Products)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is access the session in the controller. Why:

- Performance. You have fine control of how to access the Session object. If you need to read just properties of the session, then specify that you need read-only access to the session, MVC won't block the session, you'll get more performance.
- Pureness. In a pure MVC scenario, the view knows only about the model. So any value that you care about in your session must be passed as part of the model.